# How can I group AWS Cognito users based on a team or organization?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I want to create a service which allows users to sign up, but these users can be part of a team or organization; just like any other service, e.g. Slack, Trello, Google Apps, etc. So these users will need to inherit settings and permissions from the parent team or organization they have signed up as part of.

I understand there are user groups in Cognito, but these are limited to 25 per user pool as per the limits, and there is a limit of 60 pools by default. Is this even the correct way, or is there a better way to do this? Specifically is there a built in mechanism in Cognito to deal with this issue or will it require some additional work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25):

To implement multi-tenant (teams, groups, organizations) support for your application, separating them as Cognito groups isn't the right choice.

You can either provision a Userpool per tenant (you can request to increase the limit from 60 by sending a limit increase support request to AWS) or handle tenants at the application level using a single Userpool (using Cognito only to authenticate).

Note: Unless you are using separate subdomains (e.g tenant1.xyz.com) for each tenant with their own custom login page icon, you can use a single Cognito Userpool approach which is simpler.

After a user authenticates using Cognito login page, you can use the [Cognito pre token generation trigger Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html) to query user's Tenant ID from the database and add it to the JWT token so that upon verification of the token, you can retrieve the Tenant ID of the logged in user.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer - so is multi-tenancy the way to go? I want users to be able to register their own teams, and there should be no hard limit on the number of organizations that can sign up, so it sounds like a single user pool with application level logic is probably the way to go (there is no need for custom sub-domains for now).

Comment: This is the correct answer, as the AWS Cognito API does not offer an intuitive way to add a user to a group upon registration, it is an admin function and cannot be completed until the user is created.

Comment: Been struggling for two weeks (+) now how to get my head around tenant grouping, adding roles, cognito, mixin foreign identity providers, IAM, custom attributes and here in four simple paragraphs you are giving me the solution, so simple and elegant. A big big thnx - SO rocks - and U 2 ;-)

Comment: @Ashant: What about the limit of custom domains per AWS account. If creating user pool per tenant and wanted to map  tenant1.xyz.com to each cognito pool, limit of 4custom domains per account cannot be changed

Comment: @Simrankaur Reach out to AWS support, if it's a soft-limit they will increase. I've done the same for number of Cognito Pools, increasing the number.

Answer (score 7):

I think this has been changed since.

- Maximum number of groups per user pool   10,000
- Maximum number of groups that each user can belong to    100

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html

Comment: Are user groups the recommended way to handle "organizations" in an app?